# php how to create file in specific directory

Tags: php

How would I create a file in a specific directory?

this is my code at the moment :

```html
$username = $_POST["username"];

$filedir = "./u/".$username;

mkdir($filedir);

$folder = $filedir;
chmod($filedir, 0777);

$createfile = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/filename.php' );
```

I have also tried fopen but that didn't work :(

I HAVE GOT IT!!! It was

```html
$createfile = fopen('./u/'.$username.'/'.$username.'.php', 'x');
```

Thanks for all the help guy :) really appreciated.

Comment: How does this not work? Do you get any error? You need to be a bit more specific if you want help.

Comment: Did you try full path ? like "/var/www/your_domain_path/u/".$username;

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'm not even sure, might restart my server then see if its fixed anything

Comment: Maybe try `$createfile = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/'.$username.'/filename.php' );` instead

Comment: @CharlotteDunois when i try that i get an error saying " fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given "

Comment: Oh yeah, the mode is needed. `$createfile = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/u/'.$username.'/filename.php', 'w+');`

Answer (score 4):

Answer was this :

```html
$createfile = fopen('./u/'.$username.'/'.$username.'.php', 'x');
```

Thanks for all the help guy :) really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**mode** Required. Specifies the type of access you require to the file/stream.

```
fopen(filename,mode)


$createfile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/filename.php',"r"); // read only
```

Possible values:

- "r" (Read only. Starts at the beginning of the file)
- "r+" (Read/Write. Starts at the beginning of the file)
- "w" (Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a
  new file if it doesn't exist)
- "w+" (Read/Write. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a
  new file if it doesn't exist)
- "a" (Write only. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a
  new file if it doesn't exist)
- "a+" (Read/Write. Preserves file content by writing to the end of the
  file)
- "x" (Write only. Creates a new file. Returns FALSE and an error if
  file already exists)
- "x+" (Read/Write. Creates a new file. Returns FALSE and an error if
  file already exists)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with these functions -  one recursively creates a folder path and the other will create an empty file in the designated path.

```
/* recursively create folder path */
function createdir( $path=null, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        createdir( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, true );
        clearstatcache();
    }
}

/* create an empty file ensuring that path is constructed */
function createfile( $path=false, $filename=false ){
    if( $path && $filename ){
        createdir( $path );
        file_put_contents( $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename, '' );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


$dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/dir';
$filename='geronimo.txt';

$result=call_user_func('createfile', $dir, $filename );
```

Comment: I don't see why you would use `call_user_func`

Comment: it's a matter of personal preference

Answer (score 0):

I wanna make it more obvious for those guys that came here for :

**"How to create a file in a specific Address in PHP"**

```
function createFile($name, $address){
    $createfile = fopen($address.'/'.$name, 'x');
}
```

That's it . This function will take the address and the name of your file (whatever you wanna call it), and it will make it for you in that **exact address**

**ATTENTION**:
For *those who think it is the same as the answer of the other guy* , so it's not , because i had error and problem with the answer so i tried and split the `address` and the `filename` and i fixed my problem

Comment: this answer has already been given, in the question even!

Comment: @jasie its different from the answer , i had error with the answer that you are talking about ! so , i tried to post it and make it clear if anyone else has the same problem as me :))